# Where to start with Android module development with Appcelerator and Titanium

Tags: java, android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm fairly new to Appcelerator and Titanium and I want to start with developing Android modules but I have no clue where to start to be honest. I know there is a guide within the documentation of Appcelerator but that is not as detailed as I'd liked it to be and it feels somewhat out dated. I've struggled for days trying to get through the quick start without ever succeeding as a error occurred which I wasn't able to solve. There is another question just like this from 2011 where someone said it was best to just learn by reading code, but I don't understand the code at all or at least not the Kroll part of it. I've also read several blogs and tutorials but none give me any form of progress whatsoever.

So to keep it short, I'll get straight to the point.

Is there anyone who has any extra information or a detailed guide on how to start developing Android modules with Appcelerator and Titanium?

You have my thanks!

Comment: @Dahli : Can you please what is your requirement, their might be modules already available for it.

Comment: @A.A.Sebastian I know there is a module just like what I try to create, but the point of it all is that I, myself, have to make it for learning purposes. All that I ask for now is if someone has any other point for getting started with Appcelerator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Module_Development_Guide

The online docs are really the best source.

Comment: besides that, if you can't figure it out you can always connect to other developers on tislack.org